# tinymce: align footer buttons of a dialog window on the left?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

The footer buttons can be out of sight if the user is using a small screen device. Need to align the buttons to the left to avoid the issue.

I have tried using CSS to achieve that but the float left or text-align left on any of the dialog window elements did not do the work.

[Here is an example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TrPL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that tinymce uses inline style "left: 410px" on the confirm button, and "left: 493px" on the cancel button. Forcing the left style on the buttons works for me:

```
.mce-widget.mce-btn.mce-abs-layout-item.mce-first {
  left: 10px !important;
}
.mce-widget.mce-btn.mce-abs-layout-item.mce-last {
  left: 70px !important;
 }
```